# how to restrict the variable not to access outside the class in java?

Tags: java

I am using java. I know by using **private** access modifier we can restrict. But using **Reflection API** still I can access the variable outside the class. Then what is the use of private modifier here?

Comment: By default can you access private fields via reflection ?

Comment: Yes.  And I don't think there is a simple way to tell Java "no reflection on my private fields".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because reflection breaks encapsulation. You can prevent the use of the reflection api if your application is running in a security managed environment. See [Java Security Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html)

Answer (score 8):

`private` prevents you accessing it from other classes using Java.  However using JNI or a library you can do things differently. You can prevent reflection with a security manager but this is rarely needed.

Note: some libraries like Serialization need to be able to access private fields to work.

Comment: +1. To the OP, please do note that preventing reflection will break your interoperability with many Java libraries you might want to use.

Comment: @Perception  and some of the things libraries do with reflection (creating no-arg constructors that don't exist, therefore breaking final, etc.) are potentially extreme changes in your code.  A lot of times I just close my eyes and pray that they are doing things right.  :-)

Comment: @user949300 - definitely. Though, can you imagine what a library like Hibernate would look like without the ability to reflect and byte engineer classes?

Comment: @Perception or any number of libraries which manage data for you.

Answer (score 1):

> then what is the use of private modifier here

The `private` modifier is not a security mechanism; it is (one part of) an encapsulation mechanism. Hiding an object's internals from public consumption helps to keep objects in a consistent, usable state, while providing commentary about what parts of an object compose the public interface (and can be relied upon not to change).

Sure, users can use reflection to access the data in `private` fields, but they'll know they're doing something that isn't supported by the library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the java Security stuff, but I think you have to provide your own SecurityManager and override checkMemberAccess().  e.g., to prevent all reflection

```
   public void checkMemberAccess(Class<?> clazz, int which) throws AccessControlException {

      if (which != Member.PUBLIC) {
          throw new AccessControlException("No reflection on non-public fields allowed");
      }
   }
```

Obviously, in the real world, you might want to check for only a certain subset of "important" classes in the first argument.  And, as noted in many other responses, this will cause problems for a lot of 3rd party libraries.